# Custom web part in Sharepoint site header

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have some experience in SharePoint 2007, but this is my first project in SharePoint 2010.
What I need to do is this, I will try to be as clear as possible:
1 - Create a web part that will call a web application passing via querystring some parameters (and this is easy), but I have a question: in SharePoint 2010 can I develop a simple web part just with SharePoint Designer (without visual studio)?
2 - I need to put the web part that I have just created in the header of my sharepoint site, I think I should put it on my masterpage so that the web part will be anywhere in my site. Can I do this thing? How?
Thank you for your support!

Ale

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing a custom web part you should use Visual Studio.  SPD (SharePoint Designer) is designed more for the maintenance of existing assets (master pages, page layouts, web parts, etc).  Plus, I don't think it's even possible to create a 100% custom web part in SPD:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/63428ccd-729d-4d94-8a9b-d284b608929e

When you say "header" I assume you mean "at the top of the page" and not in the head tag.  Master pages usually do not have their own web part zones like page layouts do:

http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/13/so-can-you-put-web-part-zones-in-master-pages-or-what/.

That said, you can put a web part directly into a master page (which is effectively the same thing as dropping a custom user control into the master page).  If your web part must go toward the top of the page, and must be in the master page, perhaps you could not use a web part at all and create a custom user control (an ascx file).  You could then place your control toward the top of the the master page and it would be available on every page of the site (assuming multiple master pages aren't being used).  This way you don't need to worry about web parts at all.

Comment: Hi nsturdivant, I think the idea of developing a custom control is the best for me. At the end I don't need that web part in any other place of my site. Just a question: when I develop it, where should I place it? I think SharePoint will allow me just to put it in some directory. Moreover, do you know if there is some editing to do in the web config of my sharepoint site to change the trust level? Thank you very much again :)

Comment: I usually add my custom user controls and other assets (images, css files, etc.) to the Layouts folder (which should be a mapped folder within your SharePoint project).  You should create your own folder beneath the mapped folder to hold all of your custom assets.  This both logically and physically separates "out of the box" assets from your custom assets.  You can also add a mapped folder for the ControlTemplates folder and do the same.  I tend to use Layouts and enforce my own folder structure within.  You shouldn't need to alter the trust level in order to deploy a custom user control.